# Parameter name omitted

Tags: c

I have read the other questions for this particular error however I am still not able to understand why this is occurring.

When I pass a structure hsvoutput to function RGBtoH, it is meant to run function RGBtoHSV which converts RGB values to HSV values. I then want to save these HSV values in a structure which I have defined as such:

The RGB values are coming from a structure which is obtained from a PPM image.

This is the structure definition

```
struct hsvoutput
{
    float hue; // angle in degrees
    float saturation;
    float value;
};
```

This is the function

```
int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput, int i)
{
    float h;
    float s;
    float v;
    RGBtoHSV(r, g, b, &h, &s, &v);
    hsvoutput.hue[i] = h;
    hsvoutput.saturation[i] = s;
    hsvoutput.value[i] = v;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is problem exactly ?

Comment: I am receiving a parameter name omitted error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't named any variables with this: `struct hsvoutput`

`struct hsvoutput` is a type name. Furthermore, `struct` alone doesn't name a type.

So in your function, give it a name, so your signature might look like:

```
int RGBtoH(int r, int g, int b, struct hsvoutput hsv, int i)
```

And then you can populate it like:

```
RGBtoHSV(r, g, b, &hsv.hue, &hsv.saturation, &hsv.value);
```

Comment: The structure isn't populated in the RGBtoHSV function, it is populated within the RGBtoH function. But that's okay I have got it working like you said. I was wondering if you can perhaps help me further. How do I make the structure increase its size dynamically. i.e it will assign the values to the i'th element of the hsv structure?

Comment: @user3137258 ask a separate question.